# Angularjs update controller variable from directive and use in view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-controller

I've just started to use Angularjs and with the help of some stackoverflow answers I have created an image fallback directive with Angularjs.
The fallback functionality is working, but now I would like the use a boolean, a variable set in the controller I guess, in combination with ng-show in the view which indicates if the fallback image is used, or if the original image is loaded. I've changed my code several times, but it never worked....
(The teamCtrl is a seperated controller which does work and can be ignored in this issue, so I did not include the code.)

This is a piece of my html:

```
<div class="thumbnail margin-bot-20px">
    <img ng-src="../img/team{{teamCtrl.selectedteam.id}}.jpg" myfallback-src="../img/onbekend.jpg" />
</div>
<div ng-controller="fallbackController as fbCtrl">
    <p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" role="button">Wijzig foto</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" role="button" ng-show="fbCtrl.directivedummy">Verwijder foto</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

This is the directive and the directive's controller:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('PD.fallback', [])
        .directive('myfallbackSrc', myfallbackSrc);

    angular.module('PD.fallback')
        .controller('fallbackController', fallbackController);      

    function fallbackController()
    {
        this.directivedummy = false;
    };


    function myfallbackSrc()
    {
        var directive = {
            link: link
            //controller: fallbackController,   // controllerfunctie
            //controllerAs: 'vm'        // controllerAs-alias
            //bindToController: true
            //scope: {}

        };
        return directive;
    };

// 3. Link-function implementeren
    function link(scope, element, attrs)
    {
        element.bind('error', function()
        {
            scope.directivedummy = false;
            if (attrs.src != attrs.myfallbackSrc)
                attrs.$set('src', attrs.myfallbackSrc);
        });

        element.bind('load', function()
        {   
            if (attrs.src != attrs.myfallbackSrc)
                scope.directivedummy = true;
        });
    }

})();
```

So I would like to show/hide a button in the view html. The button must be visible when the src image was loaded successfully and must be hidden when the fallback image is loaded.

Hopefully someone can help me?

Comment: It seems that the directive is sharing the same scope as the controller. Why not try putting the controller in the same scope as the directive?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your are not using ControllerAs syntax, you need to trigger the $digest since the **bind** callback is happening *outside* of Angular

```
element.bind('error', function(){
            scope.$apply(function (){
              scope.directivedummy = false;
              if (attrs.src != attrs.myfallbackSrc)
                attrs.$set('src', attrs.myfallbackSrc);
             });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Trajan, I'll check if this sollution will work, but can you please also tell me what the changes will be when I do use the ControllerAs syntax, because I do prefer this syntax?

Comment: Unfortunately this sollution did not work Trajan. I've changed the default directivedummy variable to true of course in the FallbackController, but the directivedummy variable does not change after an image fallback procedure (error bind) and remains true!